# Stop the execution from the if-else when it meet the condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have trouble stopping the function to continually execute the subsequent logic when the condition is satisfied.
As shown below code, if the oustanding Balance substract reqPaidAmount is less than 0, the function should stop at this state and response the corresponding error message to the caller but the code does not stop at this stage although I use return.

Could anyone or devs suggest me the most appropriate way to stop this function be continually executed when it satisfied the given condition.

```
 items.map(async v => {
        try{
            const itemInfo = await OrderItemTransaction.findOne({
                where: { itemId: v.itemId },
                attributes: [
                    [db.Sequelize.literal('(OrderItem.unitPrice - SUM(paidAmount))'), 'outstandingBlc']
                ],
                include: [{
                    model: OrderItem,
                    attributes: ['id', 'unitPrice'],
                    on: {
                        'id': { [Op.eq]: db.sequelize.col('OrderItemTransaction.itemId') }
                    },
                    required: true
                }],
                raw: true
            });
            if (itemInfo['OrderItem.id'] == null) return void res.status(404).json({ error: "Invalid item Id" });
            const reqPaidAmount = v.paidAmount;
            const outstandingBalance = itemInfo.outstandingBlc;
            console.log(reqPaidAmount + "|" + outstandingBalance);
            if (outstandingBalance - reqPaidAmount < 0) {
                console.log("we're here 1");
                res.status(403).json({ error: `Cannot complete payment for ${v.itemId} because paid amount is ${reqPaidAmount} and outstanding balance is ${outstandingBalance}` })
                return;
            }
            else if (outstandingBalance < 0){
                console.log("we're here 2");
                res.status(403).json({error:`${v.itemId} has been paid by others`});
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(err){
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
        }
```

I keep getting this error message when I try to put

```
return res.status(403).json({ error: `Cannot complete payment for ${v.itemId} because paid amount is ${reqPaidAmount} and outstanding balance is ${outstandingBalance}` });

(node:15856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\restAPI\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\restAPI\controllers\order.js:376:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI 
flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15856) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result you want is to stop the execution for further elements, please compare forEach to plain for loop when using return;

```
    var items = [3, 5];
    
   items.forEach(x => {
       if(x === 3)
       {
          
          console.log('run')
          return;
       }
       else if(x == 5)
       {
          console.log('run');
          return;
       }
    })
    
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       if(items[i] === 3)
       {
          
          console.log('run')
          return;
       }
       else if(items[i] == 5)
       {
          console.log('run');
          return;
       }
    }
```

First one will yield 'run' twice, whereas the latter only once.

Comment: I think I put my whole code it is better to let u understand the situation.. 
I have reupdated my source code, pls have a look on it.

Comment: @MiracleHades thanks for the update. First of all, you are using .map function, that means that everytime you use 'return ;' you'll yield the undefined as an result of this operation. It is the same for using try catch and not returning nothing specific. For this case the forEach function could be better.

Comment: Have tested replaced forEach but error still persisted

Comment: @MiracleHades also, if by breaking the execution you mean not processing any other elements, simply use plain loop instead as the .map and .forEach can only be stopped by throwing an exception.

Comment: as tested by replacing " items.map(async v => {" to "for(v in items)" but problem still persisted

Comment: FYI, the error is hit by catch(err => {res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });}) but I still didn't manage to solve it..

Comment: @MiracleHades see my updated answer, and let me know if this will help you

Comment: I understood the concept and principles for loop but it does not fit my case..

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is sometimes tolerant to things like that, but have you noticed that this line

res.status(403).json({ error: `Cannot complete payment for ${v.itemId} because paid amount is ${reqPaidAmount} and outstanding balance is ${outstandingBalance}` })

is missing a semi-colon?

Comment: No really..
Although added semi-colom still not working